# Clicking button on web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to do web scraping in this web page

https://www.camara.cl/pley/pley_detalle.aspx?prmID=13505&prmBL=712960-07

And I am trying to obtain the information in the table that is contain in Autores.

I have tried using this code

```
        button=browser.find_element_by_link_text('Autores')
        button.click()
        soup_level2=BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
```

But the click is not working.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
browser=webdriver.Chrome()

url = "https://www.camara.cl/pley/pley_detalle.aspx?prmID=13505&prmBL=712960-07"

browser.get(url) #navigate to the page

browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_mainPlaceHolder_btnAutores").click()



innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
soup_level2=BeautifulSoup(innerHTML, 'html.parser')
```

PS: Your sister Vale is one of my thesis professors, small world !